# Sending and Receiving PCM Samples

Tags: html, node.js, audio, socket.io, webrtc

I've been working on making a near real-time voice chat app. The webpage will send packets to the server, and the server will save the packets to disk, and then re transmit the packets to the other connected webpages. I've tried many other solutions, but they are either laggy or they do not play. I've realized that sending PCM samples would be optimal (the server will be recording these as well), but I'm not sure how to get them to play on another client's end. I'm using NodeJS with Socket.IO. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, sending PCM samples is absolutely not optimal for realtime voice. Consider Opus in low-latency mode.

Comment: @AKX, whenever I tried to use Opus, playback required a header packet which I could not generate. If that's different in low-latency mode, could you please describe how to record over HTML5/JS in low-latency mode? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> The webpage will send packets to the server, and the server will save the packets to disk, and then re transmit the packets to the other connected webpages.

Already, this is not that efficient.  It's better when possible to send data directly from peer to peer.

> I've realized that sending PCM samples would be optimal

No, it wouldn't.  This requires more bandwidth, which is going to need better buffering, which means higher latency.  This is voice chat... no need to use a lossless encoding like PCM.

> I've been working on making a near real-time voice chat app.

This is basically the defacto primary use case that WebRTC was built for.  If you use WebRTC, you get:

- Peer-to-peer streaming (where possible)
- NAT traversal (to enable those P2P connections, where possible, or proxy them when not)
- Low latency optimization, from end to end
- Hardware acceleration (where available)
- Opus audio codec
- Automatic resampling, for compatibility and to keep latency low as things drop

In other words, this is already a solved problem with WebRTC.

Comment: I need the server to be able to receive packets, I saw that Opus is better, but I don't know how to get an Opus streamable blob from HTML5/JS Media.